# How to Comment Out a Subcategory Link in Magento's Default Sidebar

Tags: ee-1.12, sidebar

This is my first post here!

I'm only posting this question because I have researched but cannot find the answer I need here or anywhere else.

So, I'm trying to simply **comment out a specific Subcategory link in the default sidebar of a Magento site.**

And I need to do this from the Magento Admin panel without digging into the code if possible.

***I only want people who have the link to be able to get to the page.*** So this is why I don't want it showing up in the sidebar.

[image]

- If this requires an extension, please let me know.
- Or if this can only be done by getting into the code. Just let me know. I read somewhere the following is how you do it:

> /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/page . At around line
>   50 you'll see the `<div class="col-left sidebar">` line.

Ideally, I'd like to log into the Magento Admin area > find sidebar links > comment out the above indicated link.

If you need any more details please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin panel navigate to `Catalog > Manage Categories`, select the category and change *"Include in navigation"* to *"No"*.